# properly escape a string to a csv file format using javascript or dojo

Tags: javascript, csv, dojo

I would like to be able to properly escape a string so that I can use it in a cell of a csv file.  I have the code that downloads the file so I don't need that.  I don't need the code that builds the header or body of the csv file.

The strings that I want to properly escape can have any number of special chars, new lines...

Is there a function that will do this for me?  I can't use the escape() because the data needs to be human readable.

Comment: Despite the name, there are a dozen different formats of "CSV file", which can also have varying quoting rules. I think step #1 is to figure out exactly what flavor of CSV file you're trying to target.

Comment: Good point, I'll have to track this down and come up with something more specific.